# LINQ to NHibernate - compare guid with string

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

```
return queryable.Where(version => version.Id.ToString().Contains(searchKey));
```

This line will cause "ToString is not supported exception".

The goal: create search query that will compare string, int, GUID with string keyword.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: hi , i updated my answer check its helpfull to you or not i wrote note that might help you how it works...

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tested, but you could try building up your Guid-to-be-searched object before the query:

```
Guid searchGuid;
try 
{
    searchGuid = Guid.Parse(searchKey);
} 
catch (System.FormatException) 
{
   // Handle invalid search key
}

return queryable.Where(version => version.Id == searchGuid);
```

**Edit:**

Haven't tested (sorry, again), but afaik NHibernate.Linq is able to translate type conversion statements to equivalent SQL Cast functions. Maybe this should work:

```
return queryable.Where(version => (string)version.Id == searchGuid);
```

I'm not sure about the C# sintax though. In VB.NET I would write something like:

```
Return queryable.Where(Function(version) CType(version.Id,String) = searchGuid)
```

Comment: Yep, this is my plan "B" because GUID type is only one case.

Comment: "Edit" is also not supported. System.String ToString(System.Object)

Comment: -1 For even mentioning "Plan B". Please take it out, as it should be avoided at ALL costs, as you will lose indexing. It is the worst sort of wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly with LINQ (you'd have to extend the LINQ provider, which is non-trivial)

It is, however, easy to do with all the other query methods NHibernate has.

Here's an example with QueryOver:

```
return session.QueryOver<YourEntity>()
              .Where(Restrictions.Like(
                         Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String,
                                          Projections.Property<YourEntity>(
                                              version => version.Id)),
                         searchKey,
                         MatchMode.Anywhere))
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to compare like this

```
return queryable.
     Where(version => 
                 (String.Compare(version.Id.ToString(),searchkey, true)==0);
```

**Note :** Here I am considering searchkey as string anc converting version.Id guid in string and using String.Compare both string and ignoring case in string by putting true in the compare method

Comment: ToString() is not supported and Equals() seems to be too.

Comment: System.NotSupportedException {"Int32 Compare(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)"}

Comment: Yes, I noticed - not supported :)

Comment: @YevhenMartynov - what is eror you are getting over there ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for the framework 4.5 at least...

```
    Version Ver = null;
    foreach (Version V in Versions) {
        Guid g = V.ID;
        if (string.Compare(g.Value.ToString(), searchkey)) {
            Ver = V;
            break;
        }
    }

OR in LINQ

Version Ver = Version.Where(v => v.ID.Value.ToString == searchkey).FirstOrDefault;


    //Use found Ver ;-)
```